# Prove that $ 3x^{10} - y^{10} = 1991 $ has no integral solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Prove that $ 3x^{10} - y^{10} = 1991 $ has no integral solutions.

Attempt:

$ 11|1991 $
Therefore, for the equation to have a solution:
$11| 3x^{10} - y^{10} $
If I can prove that 11 does not divide $ 3x^{10} - y^{10} $ for any integral x and y, then the problem will be solved.
I am unable to prove that.
Is my method right? If yes , please help me with where i am stuck. If no, please provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, $11$ can divide $3x^{10}-y^{10}$ if $x,y$ are both divisible by $11$. But think whether there are any other possibilities (hint: Fermat's little theorem).

Comment: @Wojowu $11$ dividing both $x$ and $y$ is not really an issue....

Comment: But if x and y are multiples of 11 then $ x^{10}$ and $y^{10} $ will be multiples of $11^{10}$ . It would mean that $ 11^{10} $ divides 1991, which is not true.

Comment: I know the statement of FLT but have never implemented it in any problem before and I cannot see how to implement it here.

Comment: That's true, I was just pointing out that it's not true that 11 never divides $3x^{10}-y^{10}$ (which is apparently what OP originally aimed to show).

Comment: Challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics? Me too, you can refer to the questions I have asked in case they overlap with the ones you couldn't do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any integer $x$ we have $x^{10}\equiv\{0,1\}\pmod{11}$ due to Fermat's little theorem. Since $11\mid 1991$, assuming that $3x^{10}-y^{10}=1991$ we have that both $x$ and $y$ have to be multiples of $11$, but in such a case $3x^{10}-y^{10}$ is a multiple of $11^{10}$, while $1991$ is not.

Comment: But here we are looking at the 2 components seperately , i.e., $ 3x^{10} and y^{10} $. How do we know that $ 3x^{10} - y^{10} $ is not of the form $ k^{10} -1 $ with k and 11 coprimes? Also, how do we know that $ y^{10}$ is not of the form $ 3+11a $ for which $ 3x^{10} - y^{10} $ will be divisible by 11 if x and 11 are coprimes?

Comment: @D.K. Assume that $x^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$. Then $3x^{10}-y^{10}$ is either $2$ or $3\pmod{11}$, no good, so $x\equiv 0\pmod{11}$. Similarly, $y\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ has to hold.

Comment: I get it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your method will work. As you noticed, $11 \mid 1991$.
What about the right-hand-side?
You will have to do cases:

- (Case 1) If $x \not\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$ and $y \not\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$, then what can you say about $x^{10}$ and $y^{10}$ mod $11$? (This is Fermat's little theorem.)
- (Case 2) What if one of $x, y$ is $0$ mod $11$ but the other isn't?
- (Case 3) If both $x \equiv 0$ and $y \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$, then $11^{10} \mid x^{10}$ and $11^{10} \mid y^{10}$. What does that imply about $3x^{10} - y^{10}$?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev Well, those two statements are identical, but yes. Thanks for the catch on Case 3. Your edit was rejected but it was correct, I changed it.

Comment: @OsheenSachdev What are you talking about? I didn't. Your edit *was rejected*. Not by me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x, y \not \equiv 0$ (mod 11). Then $x^{10} \equiv 1 \equiv y^{10}$ by Fermat's Little Theorem, so we arrive at $3 \times 1 - 1 = 2 \equiv 0$ (mod 11) -- false.

Now if one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$ (mod $11$), it's clear the other must be too (owing to the fact that $3$ is coprime to $11$). But if they're both divisible by $11$, then the left-hand side is divisible by $11^{10}$... and this is certainly not true of $1991$.

Answer (score -2):

First show by putting x=2 and y=1 that has no solution and then write the comment that on taking values greater than 2 the difference becomes greater than 1991.You can show this by taking a function f(x) =3x^10-(x-1) ^10.And show that f(x) is an increasing function.
Hope this help you.

Comment: It is easy to make the difference negative, so you need "a bit" more than this. Like some result from Diophantine approximation of $\root{10}\of3$ explaining why a difference always has absolute value larger than this. If that is the case, I don't know.

Comment: You still didn't get it. You cannot assume that $y<x$.

Comment: If y $\geq$ x then 3x^10-y^10 fetch negative value and the right side is positive.If I am still wrong somewhere plz help me to spot my mistake.

Comment: $3\cdot10^{10}-11^{10}=4062575399>0.$ For every positive $k$ the leading coefficient of the polynomial
$$f(x)=3x^{10}-(x+k)^{10}$$ is equal to $2$, a positive number. Therefore $f(n)>0$ when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki